# Incorrect Syntax near 'Transaction'

Tags: c#, sql-server

Here is my code and I checked everything and I do not see any error from this but every time I click the add button, I get this error:

> Incorrect Syntax near Transaction

Can you please help me check where did I went wrong?

```
con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAPTOP-KA7UGSG3;Initial Catalog=imsysdb;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();

cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblOrders (TransactionCode, Name, Transaction, Variety, Weight, Price, Quantity, TotalPayment) VALUES(@TransactionCode, @Name, @Transaction, @Variety, @Weight, @Price, @Quantity, @TotalPayment)", con);

decimal weight = Convert.ToDecimal(cboxWeight.Text);
decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(lblPrice.Text);
int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(NumQuantity.Text);
decimal totalPayment = weight * price * quantity;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransactionCode", lblTransactionCode.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", cboxCustomerName.SelectedItem.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transaction", cboxType.SelectedItem.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Variety", cboxVariety.SelectedItem.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Weight", weight);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", price);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", quantity);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalPayment", totalPayment);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

ShowtotalPayment();

this.tblOrdersTableAdapter.Fill(this.imsysdbDataSet.tblOrders);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Transaction` is a [reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Put it in square brackets, i.e. `[Transaction]`.